# Automated Security Protocol tool that models algebraic operations

Tags: cryptanalysis, provable-security, protocol-analysis, adversarial-model, proverif

Are there any automated security protocol verification tools that model algebraic operations; specifically addition.
I am familiar with AVISPA and Verifpal, and they are both great and user-friendly tools, but they do not support addition operation.

Please help